# Laravel Relationship with Array value

Tags: mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using one to one relationship.  My model code is:

```
public function training_type()
{
    return $this->hasone('App\Training_type','id','type');
}
```

but the parameter "id" is within an array, i tried with following code but not working:

```
public function training_type()
{
    return $this->hasone('App\Training_type','types.id','type');
}
```

anyone give me good suggession.

Training_type table structure is,

```
"company_id": "company1",
"types": [
{
"id": "1",
"name": "Generic"
},
{
"id": "2",
"name": "Compensation and Benefits"
},
{
"id": "3",
"name": "Labor and Employment Law"
}
],
"updated_at": ISODate("2017-08-10T10:24:40.000+05:30")
}
```

another table structure is,

```
{
"company_id": "company1",
"title": "Fire Extinguisher\t",
"content_type": "",
"links": [
{
"link": ""
},
{
"link": ""
}
],
"updated_at": ISODate("2017-08-10T10:24:40.000+05:30"),
"type": "1"
}
```

Comment: where the `types.id` comes from ?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: You should not pass the foreign_key like what you are doing, Foreign_key is a straight forward column name for the table which you are referencing. See the example below.

Comment: i am unable to see any example ?

Comment: I am talking about my answer.

Comment: thank you, but my foreign_key value is "id", that is comes under "types" array..so only i am struggling

Comment: Please share both table schema. Thant will be helpful

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

The common practice of passing foreign_key to a relationship is :

```
public function training_type()
{
    return $this->hasone('App\Training_type','foreign_key');
}
```

The foreign_key is from the table which you want to link.

Answer (score 0):

i was using Laravel with mongodb and jenssegers/laravel-mongodb,
i had this documents from models:

User:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb8013422bb405901652cd9"),
    "name" : "ahmed",
    "email" : "ahmed@admin.com",
    "role" : {
        "name" : "admin",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bb8013422bb405901652cd2")
    }
}
```

Role:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb8013422bb405901652cd2"),
    "name" : "admin"
}
```

and i wanted to use the hasOne relation to get the use role,
i did this in the User model:

```
public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Role', '_id', 'role._id');
    }
```

as you can see, i inserted the role as an array with: id, name in the User documents in DB,
when i tested this with:

```
dd(\Auth::user()->role);
```

it worked just as fine.